# Using regex while finding web element by id in Selenium java

Tags: selenium

I am trying to locate web elements using the element id. But the id of the same web element changing between

```
Driver.findElement(By.id("ItemDetailsCompView.**Edit**ViewUIElement_Field_Tab_2_Product_Materials"))
```

and

```
Driver.findElement(By.id(ItemDetailsCompView.**Display**ViewUIElement_Field_Tab_2_Product_Materials"))
```

This results in to an error when I have hard coded for one id and the other id occurs. Is there a way to create a string that searches for Edit / Display words in the id.

I am unable to use Xpath as my webpage is complex and consists of various nested tables.

Comment: Since you already know both ids, instead of using a regex, why not check for the existence of both elements and then use the element that exists?

Comment: Or if the element is always the same type (e.g. <input>, <textarea>, etc.), using xpath to locate the object might prove more consistent.

Comment: If you want to use By.id, then you can't do much. But with xpath, you will get options like starts-with, ends-with. Same is the case with CSS selector as well.

Comment: @user2335580 Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Comment: I am trying to use and and contains operator in xpath. The code is returning a null value in place of the actual value. Am I doing something wrong? The xpath expression is  By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'EditViewUIElement_Field_Tab_1_MaterialDescription_Materials') and contains(@id,'FDOEEFPDBOMAACHHDODH.ItemDetailsCompView.')]")

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CSS selector (the syntax may be incorrect here, it's not clear what language you are using):

```
Driver.findElement(By.CssSelector([id*="ViewUIElement_Field_Tab_2_Product_Materials"]))
```

Even better if you can provide an element tag name on that.